# Wait cursor not getting dislpalyed in mfc?

Tags: mfc

I need a wait cursor to be loaded when the second page  OnWizardNext of a property sheet is clicked .This is how I had done.Actually I  designed a property sheet and now when I Click on the Next button I had activated the hourglass ,till this point everything works fine ,here arises the actual problem i.e,during that wait cursor period if I click again on Next button the dialog is getting dismissed .So,my intention is even if I click Next during the wait cursor it should not react to the click event.

```
LResult OnWizardNext()
{
CWaitCursor wait_cursor();
Sleep(10000);
return CPropertyPage::OnWizardNext()


}
```

if I remove Sleep then no wait cursor is getting loaded.What I need is even though if click on any button anything the event for that button should not get triggered until unless i am out of sleep time.

Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with the design of your wizard.  You should not be using "Sleep" as it will suspend the thread.  Moreover, the wait cursor is nothing more than a UI mechanism to indicate to the user that the code is still active.  You seem to want to use that as a determinant for when your code can continue.  Take a look at using [OnSetCursor](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131991) to provide visual feedback.  Depending on what it is you're waiting on, you may want to look at using a timer, or, perhaps a series of "flags" to indicate a "continue" condition.